# Long Table without Vertical Lines

Tags: tables, longtable

I am trying to build a long table that extends to multiple pages and I don't want vertical lines in the table but there are different sections within the table divided by horizontal lines. 
I am using the long table package but no success. I am providing the codes that I am using below:

```
     \usepackage{longtable}
     \begin{document}
     \begin{longtable}[ \centering
        \caption{Pre-Treatment Covariates for Calculating Propensity Scores}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Description}                              
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\
        \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Description}
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\
        \endfoot
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{DETERMINANTS OF SMS ISSUANCE }} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Credit Risk}} \\
        \midrule
        RWATA & Risk Weighted Asset Ratio  & Risk Weighted Assets / Total Assets \\
        LLP   & Loan Impairment  & Loan Impairment Charges / Gross Loans  \\
        NPLs  & Non-Performing Loans & NPLS / Total Loans  \\
        LLP   & Loan Loss Provision  & Loan Loss Provision / Total Loans  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Profitability }} \\
        \midrule
        NIM   & Net Interest Margin & Net Interest Income / Total Earning Assets \\
        ROA   & Return on Assets & Operating Income / Total Assets  \\
        ROE   & Return on Equity & Net Income / Total Equity  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Funding Structure and Cost }} \\
        \midrule
        LFD   & Loans Funded by Deposits  & Loans / Customer Deposits\% \\
        FTD   & Funding Through Deposits  & Customer Deposits / Total Funding excel Derivatives\% \\
        LFST  & Loans Funded by Short Term Funding  & Net Loans / Short Term Funding  \\
        LFLT  & Loans Funded by Long Term Funding  & Net Loans / Long Term Funding  \\
        FCTL  & Funding Cost for Total Liabilities  & Total Interest Expense / Total Liabilities  \\
        FCTD  & Funding Cost for Total Deposits  & Interest Expense on Deposits / Total Deposits  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Liquidity }} \\
        \midrule
        LAFST & Liquid Assets Funded by Short Term Funding  & Liquid Assets / Short Term Funding \\
        LAFLT & Liquid Assets Funded by Long Term Funding  & Liquid Assets / Long Term Funding \\
        Liq. R & Liquidity Ratio  & Cash + Securities / Total Assets \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Capital Ratios}} \\
        \midrule
        ER    & Equity Ratio  & Total Equity / Total Assets \\
        CAR   & Capital Adequacy Ratio  & (Tier 1 Capital + Tier 2 Capital) / Risk Weighted Assets \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{LOAN PORTFOLIO}} \\
        \midrule
        LBR   & Loans to Banks  & Loans to Banks / Total Loans  \\
        RMLR  & Residential Mortgage Loans Ratio & Residential Mortgage Loans / Total Loans  \\
        OMLR  & Other Mortgage Loan Ratio & Other Mortgage Loan / Total Loans  \\
        CRLR  & Consumer \& Retails Loans Ratio & Consumer \& Retails Loans / Total Loans  \\
        CCLR  & Corporate \& Commercial Loans Ratio & Corporate \& Commercial Loans / Total Loans  \\
        OLR   & Other Loans Ratio & Other Loans Ratio / Total Loans  \\
        LR    & Loan Ratio  & Total Loans / Total Assets \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{INSTITUTIONAL CHARACTERISTICS }} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Income and Cost Structure }} \\
        \midrule
        C/I   & Cost / Income & Operating Cost / Operating Income   \\
        LInc.R & Loan Income Ratio  & Interest Income on Loan / Total Loans  \\
        LIR   & Loan Interest Ratio  & Interest Income on Loans / Total Interest Income  \\
        OIR   & Other Interest Ratio  & Other Interest Income / Total Interest Income  \\
        IEDR  & Interest Expense on Deposits Ratio  & Interest Expense on Deposits / Total Interest Expense  \\
        OIER  & Other Interest Expense Ratio  & Other Interest Expense / Total Interest Expense  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Solvency }} \\
        \midrule
        D/E   & Debt to Equity Ratio & Total Liabilities / Total Equity  \\
        D/A   & Debt to Assets Ratio & Total Liabilities / Total Assets \\
        ICR   & Interest Coverage Ratio & EBIT / Total Interest Expense  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Other Institutional Characteristics }} \\
        \midrule
        AG    & Assets Growth  & Growth of Total Assets\% \\
        LG    & Loan Growth  & Growth of Gross Loans\% \\
        DPO   & Dividend Payout  & Total Dividends Paid / Net Income  \\
        Size  & Size of Bank  & Ln (Total Assets) \\
        Rep   & Reputation of Bank  & Letter of Guarantees / Total Assets \\
        COR   & Charge Off Ratio & Net Charge Offs / Total Loans  \\
        \bottomrule
        \label{tab:covariates}%
        \end{longtable}%
        \end{document}
```

The original table should look like this. 
[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`longtable` is the same as `tabular`: you need to specify the columns in the first argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
     \begin{document}
\small
     \begin{longtable}{
l
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}}%????[ \centering
\caption{Pre-Treatment Covariates for Calculating Propensity Scores\label{tab:covariates}}\\
        \toprule
        \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Description}                              
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\
        \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Description}
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
        \endfoot
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{DETERMINANTS OF SMS ISSUANCE }} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Credit Risk}} \\
        \midrule
        RWATA & Risk Weighted Asset Ratio  & Risk Weighted Assets / Total Assets \\
        LLP   & Loan Impairment  & Loan Impairment Charges / Gross Loans  \\
        NPLs  & Non-Performing Loans & NPLS / Total Loans  \\
        LLP   & Loan Loss Provision  & Loan Loss Provision / Total Loans  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Profitability }} \\
        \midrule
        NIM   & Net Interest Margin & Net Interest Income / Total Earning Assets \\
        ROA   & Return on Assets & Operating Income / Total Assets  \\
        ROE   & Return on Equity & Net Income / Total Equity  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Funding Structure and Cost }} \\
        \midrule
        LFD   & Loans Funded by Deposits  & Loans / Customer Deposits\% \\
        FTD   & Funding Through Deposits  & Customer Deposits / Total Funding excel Derivatives\% \\
        LFST  & Loans Funded by Short Term Funding  & Net Loans / Short Term Funding  \\
        LFLT  & Loans Funded by Long Term Funding  & Net Loans / Long Term Funding  \\
        FCTL  & Funding Cost for Total Liabilities  & Total Interest Expense / Total Liabilities  \\
        FCTD  & Funding Cost for Total Deposits  & Interest Expense on Deposits / Total Deposits  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Liquidity }} \\
        \midrule
        LAFST & Liquid Assets Funded by Short Term Funding  & Liquid Assets / Short Term Funding \\
        LAFLT & Liquid Assets Funded by Long Term Funding  & Liquid Assets / Long Term Funding \\
        Liq. R & Liquidity Ratio  & Cash + Securities / Total Assets \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Capital Ratios}} \\
        \midrule
        ER    & Equity Ratio  & Total Equity / Total Assets \\
        CAR   & Capital Adequacy Ratio  & (Tier 1 Capital + Tier 2 Capital) / Risk Weighted Assets \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{LOAN PORTFOLIO}} \\
        \midrule
        LBR   & Loans to Banks  & Loans to Banks / Total Loans  \\
        RMLR  & Residential Mortgage Loans Ratio & Residential Mortgage Loans / Total Loans  \\
        OMLR  & Other Mortgage Loan Ratio & Other Mortgage Loan / Total Loans  \\
        CRLR  & Consumer \& Retails Loans Ratio & Consumer \& Retails Loans / Total Loans  \\
        CCLR  & Corporate \& Commercial Loans Ratio & Corporate \& Commercial Loans / Total Loans  \\
        OLR   & Other Loans Ratio & Other Loans Ratio / Total Loans  \\
        LR    & Loan Ratio  & Total Loans / Total Assets \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{INSTITUTIONAL CHARACTERISTICS }} \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Income and Cost Structure }} \\
        \midrule
        C/I   & Cost / Income & Operating Cost / Operating Income   \\
        LInc.R & Loan Income Ratio  & Interest Income on Loan / Total Loans  \\
        LIR   & Loan Interest Ratio  & Interest Income on Loans / Total Interest Income  \\
        OIR   & Other Interest Ratio  & Other Interest Income / Total Interest Income  \\
        IEDR  & Interest Expense on Deposits Ratio  & Interest Expense on Deposits / Total Interest Expense  \\
        OIER  & Other Interest Expense Ratio  & Other Interest Expense / Total Interest Expense  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Solvency }} \\
        \midrule
        D/E   & Debt to Equity Ratio & Total Liabilities / Total Equity  \\
        D/A   & Debt to Assets Ratio & Total Liabilities / Total Assets \\
        ICR   & Interest Coverage Ratio & EBIT / Total Interest Expense  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Other Institutional Characteristics }} \\
        \midrule
        AG    & Assets Growth  & Growth of Total Assets\% \\
        LG    & Loan Growth  & Growth of Gross Loans\% \\
        DPO   & Dividend Payout  & Total Dividends Paid / Net Income  \\
        Size  & Size of Bank  & Ln (Total Assets) \\
        Rep   & Reputation of Bank  & Letter of Guarantees / Total Assets \\
        COR   & Charge Off Ratio & Net Charge Offs / Total Loans  \\
        \bottomrule

        \end{longtable}%
        \end{document}
```

Comment: It worked almost fine but two minor issues are still there. The columns are really narrow. I want to expand the columns as a lot of space is left on both sides of the paper. Moreover, when the table ends, it is still written at the end of table "Continued on next page". How I can get rid of these two issues.

Comment: @AhmedArif to get rid of the last foot use an empty `\endlastfoot` I made the columns as wide as would fit in the page, perhaps your page is wider, (the question should _always_ have a complete document so don't have to guess these things)  anyway they are specified above as 4.5cm just make them whatever width you want

Comment: thank you for your response. `\endlastfoot` perfectly worked. I increased the margins to 7 cm and table columns are expanded but the caption still remains in the narrow range and split in two lines.

Comment: @AhmedArif yes there is a separate length (`\LTcapwidth` for that, as described in the longtable manual)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use   `ltablex`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. Your table will look nicer, in my opinion, if the ‘section titles’ (in capital letters) are left-aligned too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}%
\usepackage{ltablex, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\small\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll >{\arraybackslash}X}
  \caption{Pre-Treatment Covariates for Calculating Propensity Scores}\\%
  \toprule
  \rlap{\textbf{Acronym}} & \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Description} \\
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{3}{c}%
  {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\
  \addlinespace[2ex]
  \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Description} \\
  \endhead
  \addlinespace
  \multicolumn{3}{r}{{\footnotesize[Continued on next page]}} \\
  \endfoot
  \endlastfoot
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{DETERMINANTS OF SMS ISSUANCE }} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Credit Risk}} \\
  \midrule
  RWATA & Risk Weighted Asset Ratio & Risk Weighted Assets / Total Assets \\
  LLP & Loan Impairment & Loan Impairment Charges / Gross Loans \\
  NPLs & Non-Performing Loans & NPLS / Total Loans \\
  LLP & Loan Loss Provision & Loan Loss Provision / Total Loans \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Profitability }} \\
  \midrule
  NIM & Net Interest Margin & Net Interest Income / Total Earning Assets \\
  ROA & Return on Assets & Operating Income / Total Assets \\
  ROE & Return on Equity & Net Income / Total Equity \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Funding Structure and Cost }} \\
  \midrule
  LFD & Loans Funded by Deposits & Loans / Customer Deposits\% \\
  FTD & Funding Through Deposits & Customer Deposits / Total Funding excel Derivatives\% \\
  LFST & Loans Funded by Short Term Funding & Net Loans / Short Term Funding \\
  LFLT & Loans Funded by Long Term Funding & Net Loans / Long Term Funding \\
  FCTL & Funding Cost for Total Liabilities & Total Interest Expense / Total Liabilities \\
  FCTD & Funding Cost for Total Deposits & Interest Expense on Deposits / Total Deposits \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Liquidity }} \\
  \midrule
  LAFST & Liquid Assets Funded by Short Term Funding & Liquid Assets / Short Term Funding \\
  LAFLT & Liquid Assets Funded by Long Term Funding & Liquid Assets / Long Term Funding \\
  Liq. R & Liquidity Ratio & Cash + Securities / Total Assets \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Capital Ratios}} \\
  \midrule
  ER & Equity Ratio & Total Equity / Total Assets \\
  CAR & Capital Adequacy Ratio & (Tier 1 Capital + Tier 2 Capital) / Risk Weighted Assets \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{LOAN PORTFOLIO}} \\
  \midrule
  LBR & Loans to Banks & Loans to Banks / Total Loans \\
  RMLR & Residential Mortgage Loans Ratio & Residential Mortgage Loans / Total Loans \\
  OMLR & Other Mortgage Loan Ratio & Other Mortgage Loan / Total Loans \\
  CRLR & Consumer \& Retails Loans Ratio & Consumer \& Retails Loans / Total Loans \\
  CCLR & Corporate \& Commercial Loans Ratio & Corporate \& Commercial Loans / Total Loans \\
  OLR & Other Loans Ratio & Other Loans Ratio / Total Loans \\
  LR & Loan Ratio & Total Loans / Total Assets \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{INSTITUTIONAL CHARACTERISTICS }} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Income and Cost Structure }} \\
  \midrule
  C/I & Cost / Income & Operating Cost / Operating Income \\
  LInc.R & Loan Income Ratio & Interest Income on Loan / Total Loans \\
  LIR & Loan Interest Ratio & Interest Income on Loans / Total Interest Income \\
  OIR & Other Interest Ratio & Other Interest Income / Total Interest Income \\
  IEDR & Interest Expense on Deposits Ratio & Interest Expense on Deposits / Total Interest Expense \\
  OIER & Other Interest Expense Ratio & Other Interest Expense / Total Interest Expense \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Solvency }} \\
  \midrule
  D/E & Debt to Equity Ratio & Total Liabilities / Total Equity \\
  D/A & Debt to Assets Ratio & Total Liabilities / Total Assets \\
  ICR & Interest Coverage Ratio & EBIT / Total Interest Expense \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Other Institutional Characteristics }} \\
  \midrule
  AG & Assets Growth & Growth of Total Assets\% \\
  LG & Loan Growth & Growth of Gross Loans\% \\
  DPO & Dividend Payout & Total Dividends Paid / Net Income \\
  Size & Size of Bank & Ln (Total Assets) \\
  Rep & Reputation of Bank & Letter of Guarantees / Total Assets \\
  COR & Charge Off Ratio & Net Charge Offs / Total Loans \\
  \bottomrule
  \label{tab:covariates}%
\end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]